# How to grep or awk through ghe-logs-tail?

Tags: github, awk, grep, pipe, github-enterprise

Github Enterprise Server comes with a utility:

```
ghe-logs-tail
```

this tails all GHE Server logs simultaneously and prints the flow to the console for the user to view.

When trying to grep through these through, eg. for the "error" string like so:

```
ghe-logs-tail | grep --line-buffered -i "error"
```

The console will not print the flow and instead includes an error that some log files could not be opened for some reason.

```
$ ghe-logs-tail | grep --line-buffered -i "error"
/var/log/github/audit.log /var/log/github/auth.log /var/log/github/exceptions.log /var/log/github/gitauth.log /var/log/github/personal.log /var/log/github/production.log /var/log/github/resqued.log /var/log/github/unicorn.log /var/log/enterprise-manage/login_attempts.log /var/log/enterprise-manage/unicorn.log /var/log/github/auth.log /var/log/auth.log /var/log/nginx/alambic.assets.error.log /var/log/nginx/alambic.assets.log /var/log/nginx/alambic.avatars.error.log /var/log/nginx/alambic.avatars.log /var/log/nginx/alambic.error.log /var/log/nginx/alambic.log /var/log/nginx/avatars.error.log /var/log/nginx/avatars.log /var/log/nginx/credits.error.log /var/log/nginx/credits.log /var/log/nginx/enterprise-manage.error.log /var/log/nginx/enterprise-manage.log /var/log/nginx/error.log /var/log/nginx/gist.error.log /var/log/nginx/gist.log /var/log/nginx/github.error.log /var/log/nginx/github.log /var/log/nginx/pages.error.log /var/log/nginx/pages.log /var/log/nginx/raw.error.log /var/log/nginx/raw.log /var/log/nginx/render.error.log /var/log/nginx/render.log /var/log/nginx/static-maintenance.error.log /var/log/nginx/static-maintenance.log /var/log/nginx/storage.error.log /var/log/nginx/storage.log /data/user/common/ghe-config.log /var/log/syslog /var/log/dmesg /var/log/mysql/*.log /var/log/redis/redis.log /var/log/haproxy.log
==> /var/log/nginx/alambic.assets.error.log <==
==> /var/log/nginx/alambic.avatars.error.log <==
==> /var/log/nginx/alambic.error.log <==
==> /var/log/nginx/avatars.error.log <==
==> /var/log/nginx/credits.error.log <==
==> /var/log/nginx/enterprise-manage.error.log <==
==> /var/log/nginx/error.log <==
==> /var/log/nginx/gist.error.log <==
==> /var/log/nginx/github.error.log <==
tail: cannot open '/var/log/mysql/*.log' for reading==> /var/log/nginx/pages.error.log <==
==> /var/log/nginx/raw.error.log <==
: No such file or directory==> /var/log/nginx/render.error.log <==

==> /var/log/nginx/static-maintenance.error.log <==
==> /var/log/nginx/storage.error.log <==
tail: cannot open '/var/log/redis/redis.log' for reading: No such file or directory
```

What is the correct way to do this with a native tool like grep/awk?

I would obviously like to have all lines that contain the matching string printed out in real time to the console.

Comment: Looks to me like it's doing exactly what you asked for, printing all lines that contain `error`, but some files that `ghe-logs-tail` is trying to tail don't exist or aren't readable so it's telling you about those (on stderr presumably).

Answer (score 0):

you can filter out grep errors by routing them to the null device (blackhole)

```
... | grep ... 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Looks to me like the errors are coming from ghe-logs-tail, not grep.

Comment: Oh, didn't pay attention. So should move it before the pipe then. If it's a stream consistent script it should work but have no idea what that is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. `ghe-logs-tail >2/dev/null | grep -i "error"` suppresses the errors but it doesn't fix the issue that some of the logs cannot be opened for some reason when using grep.

Comment: @pythonInRelay - again, it's not **grep** that can't open any files, read the error messages "**tail**: cannot open..." plus the fact that adding `>2/dev/null` after the tail command suppresses them. Those errors will be present whether you pipe to grep or not.

Comment: @EdMorton how then do I avoid these errors? I don't care about surpressing them. I want still to be able to open these log files and read them in real-time using grep.

Comment: you have to fix `ghe-logs-tail` in order to not to get errors.